# How to use Vlookup with match to return format

Tags: excel, vba, format, vlookup

I am trying to do Vlookup but as all of you know vlookup cannnot return the format together with value. I have read online that I can use Vlookup with Match to return the format. So please teach me how to return the value together with the format. Please take note that not all the values in "look" can be found so that is why IsError is used. Thanks for your help.

```
 With Sheet3 
 x = 2
 Do Until IsEmpty(.Range("F" & x).value)
    look = .Range("F" & x).value
    result = Application.VLookup(look, Sheet2.Range("B:H"), 2, False)
    If Not IsError(result) Then
        .Range("G" & x).value = result
    Else
        .Range("G" & x).value = " "
    End If
    x = x + 1
 Loop
 End With
```

Comment: "Format" can mean different things, can you specify? Format of the cell, format of the data etc.

Comment: I mean the color of the cell and the border

Comment: See my answer below

Answer (score 0):

This can generally be used to return the format of a cell:

```
Range.DisplayFormat
```

MS documentation is [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838814%28v=office.15%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

Color of a cell:

```
 getColorIndex = ActiveCell.Interior.ColorIndex
```

Set border information:

```
 With Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B2").Borders(xlEdgeBottom) 
   .LineStyle = xlContinuous 
   .Weight = xlThin 
   .ColorIndex = 3 
 End With
```

Just reverse the code to check for a value instead of setting it. Documentation [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff822605.aspx).

Hope this helps!

Comment: If you wont to use it with a specific cell you have to drop the "DisplayFormat" part. Just change
`getColorIndex = ActiveCell.DisplayFormat.Interior.ColorIndex`
to
`getColorIndex = ActiveCell.Interior.ColorIndex`

Comment: If this answered your question, consider accepting it as an answer.